# Is there any method to select only one series marker state in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

As given in the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-states-select-linewidth/) we can select more than one point by holding CNTL key! Is there any way by which user is allowed only to select one point at a time?

```
                marker: {
                states: {
                    select: {
                        lineWidth: 3
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can code of the behavior yourself instead of using `allowPointSelect`:

```
      series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function(event) {
                        this.select();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tSJfT/).